# d3 svg attrtween each by each

Tags: d3.js, svg

[demo](https://codepen.io/yang25/pen/MOzrZW)

The demo as you can see, I want to do the effect that the box rotates by itself like the red boxes below (div version).

I try to use svg to rewrite it, but svg version seems to rotate all svg
How can I let them rotate by themselves like the div version???

Here is the svg version's main logic:

```
d3.selectAll('g')
  .each(function (data, index) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition('t3')
        .delay(800)
        .duration(2500)
        .styleTween('transform', function () {
        return d3.interpolateString('rotateY(0deg)', 'rotateY(360deg)');
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to get the SVG elements to transform around their centres.

```
g {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

E.g.

```js
d3.selectAll('g')
  .each(function (data, index) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition('t3')
        .delay(800)
        .duration(2500)
        .styleTween('transform', function () {
        return d3.interpolateString('rotateY(0deg)', 'rotateY(360deg)');
      })
  })


d3.selectAll('div.box')
  .each(function (data, index) {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition('t3')
        .delay(800)
        .duration(2500)
        .styleTween('transform', function () {
        return d3.interpolateString('rotateY(0deg)', 'rotateY(360deg)');
      })
  })
```

```css
rect {
  fill:rgb(121,0,121);
  stroke-width:1;
  stroke:rgb(0,0,0);
}

.section {
  display: flex;
}

.box { 
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
} 

g {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<h3>still trying: </h3>
<div>
<svg width="800" height="100">
  <g>        
    <rect x="10" y="30" width="50" height="50"></rect> 
  </g> 
  <g>        
    <rect x="70" y="30" width="50" height="50"></rect> 
  </g>   
  <g>        
    <rect x="130" y="30" width="50" height="50"></rect> 
  </g> 
  <g>        
    <rect x="190" y="30" width="50" height="50"></rect> 
  </g>     
</svg>
  
</div>

<h3>expected: </h3>
<div class="section">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div> 
</div>
```